# How to use 'tap' in ThumbnailsCard

Tags: javascript, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to use the tap option inside ThumbnailCard (TC) using MS bot framework.

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botframework-schema/thumbnailcard?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#tap) I saw that TC has the following properties:

title, subtitle, text, buttons, images and tap.

On [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/06.using-cards/dialogs/mainDialog.js), I can't see the tap property and I'm wondering if it's should be supported and how to use it if so.

```
const thumbnailCard = CardFactory.thumbnailCard(
        'BotFramework Thumbnail Card',
        [{ url: 'https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7ff5/e07cfef0-aa3b-40bb-9baa-7c9ef8ff7ff5/buildreactionbotframework_960.jpg' }],
        [{
            type: 'openUrl',
            title: 'Get started',
            value: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/'
        }],
        {
            subtitle: 'Your bots — wherever your users are talking.',
            text: 'Build and connect intelligent bots to interact with your users naturally wherever they are, from text/sms to Skype, Slack, Office 365 mail and other popular services.'
        }
    );
```

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

You've already linked to the documentation where you can see that `tap` is a card action. You can click on the link in that thumbnail card documentation yourself to see the [card action documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botframework-schema/cardaction), and you can also see an example of a card action in the `buttons` property. You could use that information to try something like this:

```
const thumbnailCard = CardFactory.thumbnailCard(
    'BotFramework Thumbnail Card',
    [{ url: 'https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7ff5/e07cfef0-aa3b-40bb-9baa-7c9ef8ff7ff5/buildreactionbotframework_960.jpg' }],
    [],
    {
        subtitle: 'Your bots — wherever your users are talking.',
        text: 'Build and connect intelligent bots to interact with your users naturally wherever they are, from text/sms to Skype, Slack, Office 365 mail and other popular services.',
        tap: {
            type: 'openUrl',
            title: 'Get started',
            value: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/'
        }
    }
);
```

Because cards are UI elements, you should keep in mind that all card behavior is channel-specific and you shouldn't expect `tap` to work on all channels. You should always test your cards on each channel you're targeting to see what works, as explained in the [card support doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference#card-support-by-channel).

> These categories are intentionally broad and don't fully explain how every card feature is supported in each channel due to the many possible combinations of cards, features, and channels. Please use this table as a base reference, but test each of your cards in the desired channel(s).